# Derivation of Time-Reversed Ket for a Spin-1/2 Particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

I'm self-learning quantum mechanics from the 3rd edition of Sakurai and Napolitano's *Modern Quantum Mechanics*, and I've hit a bump in a derivation. The authors note that the eigenket of $\mathbf{S}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ with eigenvalue $\hbar/2$ can be written as

\begin{equation*}
|\hat{\mathbf{n}};+\rangle = e^{-iS_{z}\alpha/\hbar}e^{-iS_{y}\beta/\hbar}|+\rangle
\end{equation*}

where $\mathbf{S}$ is the spin angular momentum operator; $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are, respectively, the polar and azimuthal angles characterizing the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{ n}}$; and $|+\rangle$ is the eigenvector of $S_{z}$ with eigenvalue $\hbar/2$.

I understand the derivation up to this point. They then say that

\begin{equation}
\Theta|\hat{\mathbf{n}};+\rangle = e^{-iS_{z}\alpha/\hbar}e^{-iS_{y}\beta/\hbar}\Theta|+\rangle = \eta|\hat{\mathbf{n}};-\rangle
\end{equation}

where $|\hat{\mathbf{n}};-\rangle$ is the eigenket of $\mathbf{S}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ with eigenvalue $-\hbar/2$, and $\Theta$ is the time-reversal operator which, for an angular momentum operator $\mathbf{J}$, satisfies

\begin{equation*}
\Theta \mathbf{J}\Theta^{-1} = -\mathbf{J}.
\end{equation*}

I'm not sure how they use the previous equation to get to the one before that. Is it true that because $\Theta \mathbf{J}\Theta^{-1} = -\mathbf{J}$, then a similar rule holds for the exponential of the components of $\mathbf{J}$? Also, by writing $\eta$, it seems like the authors are indicating a phase factor rather than an operator, but I'm not sure. I think I could figure it out once I understand why

\begin{equation*}
\Theta e^{-iS_{z}\alpha/\hbar}e^{-iS_{y}\beta/\hbar}|+\rangle = e^{-iS_{z}\alpha/\hbar}e^{-iS_{y}\beta/\hbar}\Theta|+\rangle.
\end{equation*}

Frankly, I'm not even sure this forum is the right place to ask this question, so I apologize in advance if it's inappropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $J$ be any component of $S$.

From $\Theta J \Theta^{-1} = -J$ we obtain $\Theta J = - J \Theta $.
Since $\Theta$ is anti-linear we have $\Theta iJ = -i \Theta J = iJ \Theta$.

Further
$\Theta J^2 \Theta^{-1} = \Theta J \Theta^{-1} \Theta J \Theta^{-1} = J^2$. So that $\Theta J^2 = J^2 \Theta$.

By induction we obtain $ \Theta (iJ)^n = (iJ)^n \Theta$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

And therefore
$$ \Theta \exp (iJ) = \Theta \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} (iJ)^n = \exp(iJ) \Theta ,$$
which gives us the identity you have asked about (putting the $-$, $\hbar$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ in front of $J$ does not change anything because they are real numbers).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, then, I guess we have that for any anti-linear operator $\Theta$ and any self-adjoint operator (what other requirements are needed?) $J$ that is odd under time reversal, we have that $\Theta$ commutes with the exponential of $iJ$. That's interesting!

Answer (score 3):

jd27 answers your question.

I just wanted to add that it is not obvious that $\Theta |+\rangle\propto |-\rangle$ once you have your last identity.

This is why I prefer proving things in one go. Noting that:
$$
(n\cdot \sigma)|n,+\rangle =|n,+\rangle
$$
using the conjugation relation:
$$
\Theta (n\cdot \sigma) \Theta^{-1}=-n\cdot \sigma
$$
so:
$$
(n\cdot \sigma) \Theta |n,+\rangle =-\Theta|n,+\rangle
$$
i.e. $\Theta |n,+\rangle$ is a $-1$ eigenstate of $n\cdot \sigma$ so:
$$
\Theta |n,+\rangle \propto |n,-\rangle
$$
Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it true then that Θ|,+⟩ is the eigenvector of ̂ ⋅ corresponding to the eigenvalue −1? It seems like the moral of the story is that Θ|,+⟩ and |,−⟩ lie on the same ray, which makes a lot of sense. Your proof is elegant and eminently lucid!

Comment: No problem. Yes, that’s what I showed. To complete the proof, you just need to check that $\Theta|n,+\rangle\neq0$.